# Angular- You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. ts 1005 : expected

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting error for the following snippet of code

```
const index = this.dishIds?.indexOf(dishId);
this.prev= this.dishIds?[(this.dishIds?.length + index - 1) % this.dishIds?.length];
this.next= this.dishIds?[(this.dishIds?.length + index + 1) % this.dishIds?.length];
```

Error:
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |         var _a, _b, _c, _d, _e;

> ```
>     const index = (_a = this.dishIds) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.indexOf(dishId);
>  this.prev = this.dishIds ? [(((_b = this.dishIds) === null || _b === void 0 ? void 0 : _b.length) + index - 1) % ((_c = this.dishIds) === null || _c === void 0 ? void 0 : _c.length)] : ; 
>    this.next = this.dishIds ? [(((_d = this.dishIds) === null || _d === void 0 ? void 0 : _d.length) + index + 1) % ((_e = this.dishIds) === null || _e === void 0 ? void 0 : _e.length)] : ;
> ```

Error in the VS Code editor:

> ':' expected.ts(1005)

I believe I need only the semi-colon at the end of the expression which has been added. Not sure what else should be added to the code. Reading other threads, I believe it might be a tsconfig issue, but not sure what I need to modify. Would appreciate the help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The operator that you intend to use is called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and which is syntactically expressed as `?.` and not `?`

`?` is called [Conditional (Ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

In the case where the error says `':' expected.ts(1005)`, the operator is getting treated as a `Conditional (Ternary) Operator` and not as `Optional Chaining` operator. For it to be treated as `optional chaining`, you will have to use a `.` beside `?`

For example...

```
dishIds?.[(dishIds?.length + index - 1) % dishIds?.length]; //<-- Mark the ?. after dishIds?.[......]
dishIds?.[(dishIds?.length + index + 1) % dishIds?.length];
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Appreciate the response. Still trying to get my way around TS syntax